# Javascript dynamic element inside dynamic element

Tags: javascript, dynamic, element

I'm  trying to add an dynamically created element ( with `document.createElement('span')` ) inside an dynamically created div.

This is my code:

```
// Newplayer div holder
var newPlayer = document.createElement('div');
newPlayer.setAttribute('id', 'player_' + playerID);
newPlayer.setAttribute('class', 'player_entry');
newPlayer.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: ' + getRandomColor());

// Points holder
var playerTotalPointsHolder = document.createElement('div');
playerTotalPointsHolder.setAttribute('id', 'player_' + playerID + "_total_holder");
playerTotalPointsHolder.setAttribute('class', 'player_total_holder');

var playerTotalPoints = document.createElement('span');
playerTotalPoints.setAttribute('id', 'player_' + playerID + "_total");
playerTotalPoints.setAttribute('class', 'player_total');
playerTotalPoints.innerHTML = 0;

// Put the pieces together
playerTotalPointsHolder.innerHTML = "Total: " + playerTotalPoints;
```

But the output is:

```
Playername [object HTMLDivElement]
```

So my question is, how can i insert the element inside the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
playerTotalPointsHolder.innerHTML = "Total: " + playerTotalPoints;
```

to this:

```
playerTotalPointsHolder.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode('Total: ')
);
playerTotalPointsHolder.appendChild(
  playerTotalPoints
);
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. But what's the effort of creating an textnode instead of just inserting an string?

Comment: @Mathlight It's more consistent, and it doesn't destroy sibling elements when they exist. There are no practical advantages for your specific case.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your explanation. I'll accept your answer because of the consistent part.

Comment: @Mathlight I agree with sabof, it is usually discouraged to change innnerHTML directly (see for example ["Security considerations" here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML))

Answer (score 1):

```
playerTotalPointsHolder.innerHTML = "Total: ";
playerTotalPointsHolder.appendChild(playerTotalPoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) for this:

```
// Setting total score...
playerTotalPoints.innerHTML = "Total: " + 0;

// And pushing `span` to `div`
playerTotalPointsHolder.appendChild(playerTotalPoints);
```

With `playerID` 1, this will result in the following HTML:

```
<div id="player_1_total_holder" class="player_total_holder">
   <span id="player_1_total" class="player_total">Total: 0</span>
</div>
```

However, I suggest that instead of using `span` you should use `p` as paragraph for text. But even then, same principle applies for pushing element inside an element.

Answer (score 0):

You created your elements but you didn't append them anywhere in your DOM. You need, at the end of your code, do something like this:

```
playerTotalPointsHolder.appendChild(playerTotalPoints);
newPlayer.appendChild(playerTotalPointsHolder);
someDOMElementInYourDocument.appendChild(newPlayer);
```

Comment: please provide some description